# Blog data saving problmes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, blogger

i have made a button in blog as helped by people here on this forum and that button increase the counter value everytime the button is clicked but i wanted the button to save the value so that when other users click the button the value should increase, but as soon as the page is refreshes the value is set to 0 again,

i have thought of an idea that

once the guy clicks the button it will post the value in the comment section but the comment will be kept hidden, and when somebody else clicks the button again, it retrieves the value from the comment and adds 1 to that and again updates it in the comment section,

this is just a hypothesis and i am not that genius to carry such a thing out! guys please help me out some other alternative method cuz i cant afford to pay for database hosting... thanks and i will be grateful if u helped

Comment: [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), and many others have free plans, that might still be useful to you.

Comment: tried firebase so easy to use thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If don't want/can't use a database, you can use a file to store the counter.
Inside the file, you can simply store a number, and when the button is clicked, read the number from the file, increment the number by one and write the new number to the file.

Comment: if u dont mind can u please tell me how to do that in detail cuz i am really new to web thing

Comment: You need to use a server-side language like PHP or Ruby to read and write to files on the server. There's more to it and I won't go into specifics - you should read about it, there's plenty of material online.